How to set sans and mono fonts with \newfontfamily?
Consider the following example. It works exactly like expected:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{KpRoman-Regular.otf}
\setsansfont{NewCMSans10-Book.otf}
\setmonofont{FreeMono.ttf}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\f@family

\sffamily

\f@family

\ttfamily

\f@family
\makeatother
\end{document}

Theoretically even when a \newfontfamily is set, I expect similar results. Unfortunately, I can only set one font. So I lack full control with \newfontfamily. The current results don't and can't capture the cases where I want different fonts for different in sf, tt contexts (compare with example 1).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\kpfont{KpRoman-Regular.otf}
% Some command here to set sans font WHEN \kpfont is active.
% Some command here to set mono font WHEN \kpfont is active.

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\f@family

\kpfont

\f@family

\sffamily

\f@family

\ttfamily

\f@family
\makeatother
\end{document}


Why should it be considered “strange”? You asked for the monospaced family and you get what you asked for.

@egreg getting monospace font is not strange, getting it from KP family is strange. I didn't add it anywhere. fontspec picked up automatically. That's good, but why not for sans?

I can see \setmonofont, can’t you?

@egreg That will actually set main mono font. I don't want the main font to be changed. Suppose I want to delimit my macro \kpfont and outside it I want lm family, then?

Sorry, but it’s difficult to understand what you’d expect

\ttfamily sets a family it does not set "the monospace version of the current family" so you just want two instances of \newfontfamily one defining \kpfont and another defining (say) \kpttfont  thne use \kpfont and \kpttfont to select them

@egreg I am so sorry, I indeed had missed that extra \setmonofont. Now the question is edited and the irrelevant part is removed for the future readers.

After long consultation with my crystal ball, I think I've understood your aim.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont
%\setsansfont
%\setmonofont

\newfontfamily\kprm{KpRoman}[NFSSFamily=kprm]
\newfontfamily\kpsf{KpSans}[NFSSFamily=kpsf]
\newfontfamily\kptt{KpMono}[NFSSFamily=kptt]

\newenvironment{kp}{%
  \par
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{kprm}%
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{kpsf}%
  \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{kptt}%
  \normalfont % reinitialize
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\section{Standard}

This section uses the font defined with \texttt{main}

Roman font \fontname\font

\textsf{Sans font \fontname\font}

\texttt{Mono font \fontname\font}

\begin{kp}
\section{Kp}

This section uses the font defined with \texttt{kp}

Roman font \fontname\font

\textsf{Sans font \fontname\font}

\texttt{Mono font \fontname\font}
\end{kp}

\end{document}

In the kp environment, the various font families are replaced with the Kp ones.

A few more details. Fonts are selected according to four orthogonal axes: encoding, family name, weight, shape. A “pure” LaTeX document starts up with encoding=OT1, family=cmr, weight=m (for medium) and shape=n (normal). The standard families are also cmss and cmtt.
When LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX are used, the encoding becomes TU and the initial family is lmr, for sans serif it is lmss and for monospaced it is lmtt.
When you do \setmainfont, you select what the engine will interpret as the “Roman font”, that is \rmfamily, by suitably defining \rmdefault. Similarly, \setsansfont and \setmonofont suitably define \sfdefault and \ttdefault to select the appropriate families.
There is no “axis” selecting a “superfamily”, which is apparently what you want to do.
With \newfontfamily you set up a family. For example
\newfontfamily{\kpfont}{KpRoman}

will make \kpfont to change just the family attribute; the independence of the various attributes would make
\textbf{abc\kpfont def}

to select the standard boldface for “abc” and KpRoman boldface for “def”. However, if you issue \sffamily in the scope of \kpfont, the family attribute is changed to what's stored in \sfdefault, which has nothing to do with Kp.
In order to do its work, fontspec assigns names for \rmdefault, \sfdefault and \ttdefault built from the font names themselves, unless you specify a name yourself, like I do in the \newfontfamily declarations: this is important because it's generally difficult to guess what the automatically assigned name would be.
The kp environment, in a sense, sets up the “superfamily̦” you seem to want by locally redefining \rmdefault, \sfdefault and \ttdefault and initializing with \normalfont that, basically, does
\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont


I am sorry for the guesswork you had to do, but you indeed have correctly understood my objective. The NFSS parameter was the key to this problem. I wasn't aware about its usage. Now it is clear. Thanks a lot for all the additional pointers too.

\ttfamily changes the font family. The family axis just corresponds to distinct names it does not select "the monospace version of the current roman family" which seems to be what you want, so simply use
\newfontfamily\kpfont{KpRoman-Regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\kpttfont{KpMono-Regular.otf}

then \kpfont and \kpttfont select the kp roman and monospace and \rmfamily and \ttfamily select the default (latin modern) roman and monospace.

@Niranjan shame: I nearly pointed out you could  define a command setting both, but thought that was clear (you can aways do that for any combination of things in TeX:-) of course egreg getting the tick is a disaster (I don't mind so much not getting it myself;-)

Hahahaha, okay I am out of words now :P I like this cute and casual banter between you all.
